# How to create new users in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I want to create new user in Pentaho BA, but not by adding one by one.I have a list of users in a data source,I want to know if there is a solution to create the users in one time .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could user the [createUser](http://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform500/webservice500/resource_UserRoleDaoResource.html#path__userroledao_createUser.html) function on REST API.

Examples [here](http://rpbouman.blogspot.it/2014/10/performing-administrative-tasks-on.html).

Comment: Thanks, it is what i was searching :)